# Parallel Resonance circuit Q factor formula Clarification

Tags: parallel, resonance

I'm confused with the formula of Q factor in parallel resonance because in other books its different
is it okay to be like this ?

**A. This is from the  Electronics Tutorial Website**
[image: Electronics Tutorial]
**A. This is from a book**

[image: John Bird's book]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm confused with the formula of Q factor in parallel resonance
>   because in other books its different*

In the first case, they are talking about the Q factor of a perfect inductor, L in parallel with a resistor. In the second case they are talking about the Q factor of a resistor in series with the inductor, L.

I know it can be confusing and some websites don't make this explicitly clear.